# How to visualize my ruby program which simulates the growth of a tree?

Tags: ruby, visualization, interactive

As part of Cpine's tutorial [enter link description here](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_09.html), I used Ruby to write a program which simulates the growth of a orange tree: 
1. You plant it
2. You wait
3. It grows
4. You can harvest its fruit
and so on...

Now I would like to visualize that, as simply as possible. Do you have any ideas or suggetions on how to do that? I.e. provide it with an interactive userface which actually shows the user the tree as it grows?
The simpler the better.

Here's the code:

```
class OrangeTree

  def initialize
    @age = 0
    @orangeCount = 0
    @height = 0
    puts "You planted a tree"
    height
    countTheOranges
    waitOneYear
  end

  def waitOneYear
    puts "Do you want to wait another year?"
    wantsToWait = gets.downcase.chomp
    if wantsToWait == "yes"
      puts
      oneYearPasses
    else
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    end
  end

  def height
    puts "The tree is #{@height} ft tall"
  end

  def oneYearPasses
    @orangeCount = 0
    puts "Another year has passed"
    @age = @age + 1
    puts "The tree is #{@age.to_s} years old"
    @height = @height + 1
    height
    orangeGrowth
    countTheOranges
    pickAnOrange
    waitOneYear
  end

  def orangeGrowth
    @orangeCount = @orangeCount + @age - 3
  end

  def countTheOranges
    if @orangeCount < 1
      puts "There are still no oranges"
    elsif @orangeCount == 1
      puts "There is one orange on the tree"
      puts "Would you like to eat an orange?"
      @wantsApple = gets.downcase.chomp
    else
    puts "There are #{@orangeCount} oranges on the tree"
    puts "Would you like to eat an orange?"
    @wantsApple = gets.downcase.chomp
    end
  end

  def pickAnOrange
    if @orangeCount > 0
      if @wantsApple == "yes"
        @orangeCount = @orangeCount - 1
        puts "That was delicious"
        if @orangeCount < 1
          puts "There are no more oranges left"
        elsif @orangeCount == 1
          puts "There is one more orange left"
        else
          puts "There are #{@orangeCount} oranges left"
          puts "Would you like another one?"
          @wantsApple = gets.downcase.chomp
          if @wantsApple == "yes"
            pickAnOrange
          end
        end
      else
        puts "Alright, hombre"
      end
    end
  end

end

tree = OrangeTree.new
```

Comment: I have just one question... How do you get oranges on a lemon tree?!? No, wait, that's not it... Have you seen [this overview of Ruby GUI in 2018](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/An-overview-of-ruby-gui-development-in-2018/), or [this curated list of GUI frameworks](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/GUI_Frameworks)? For starters, probably pick up your Shoes, read the tutorial - really good for a learner, I think.

Comment: Good point... oranges from a lemon tree :P
Thank you so much for the resources @Amadan!!!

Comment: Shoes is a standalone program where beginners in Ruby can mess about with UI. If you want to use your standard Ruby, you should pick one of the others.

Comment: Another option is to use JRuby and a Java GUI library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of iGian and anquegi's answers (THANK YOU!).

You can try the game out at: https://repl.it/@benisburgers/OrangeTree

```
class OrangeTree

  def initialize
    @age = 0
    @orangeCount = 0
    @height = 0
    puts "Welcome to the orange-tree game. You can leave the game at any time by typing 'exit'. "
    puts "Would you like to plant an orange tree?"
    getFirstInput
  end

  def getFirstInput
    @firstInput = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @firstInput == 'yes'
      drawTree
      puts @tree
      puts "Congratulations. You have planted an orange tree"
      puts "There are still no oranges. Would you like to wait a few more years?"
      waitFewYears?
    elsif @firstInput == 'no'
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    elsif @firstInput == "exit"
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    else
      puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
      getFirstInput
    end
  end

  def waitFewYears?
    @input = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @input == 'yes'
      puts "Here you go"
      @age = 4
      orangeGrowth
      countTheOranges
    elsif @input == 'no'
      puts "Gooybye"
      exit
    elsif @input == 'exit'
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    else
      puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
      waitFewYears?
    end
  end

  def waitOneYear?
    puts "Do you want to wait another year?"
    @wantsToWait = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @wantsToWait == "yes"
      puts
      oneYearPasses
    elsif @wantsToWait == "no"
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    elsif @wantsToWait == "exit"
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    else
      puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
      waitOneYear?
    end
  end

  def oneYearPasses
    @orangeCount = 0
    @tree.replace(@originalTree)
    puts "Another year has passed"
    @age = @age + 1
    puts "The tree is #{@age.to_s} years old"
    @height = @height + 1
    orangeGrowth
    countTheOranges
    pickAnOrange?
  end

  def orangeGrowth
    if @age < 20
      @orangeCount = @orangeCount + @age - 3
    else
      @orangeCount = 17
    end
    i = 0
    while i < @orangeCount
      @tree["_"] = ""
      i = i + 1
    end
    puts @tree
  end

  def countTheOranges
    if @orangeCount < 1
      puts "There are still no oranges"
    elsif @orangeCount == 1
      puts "There is one orange on the tree"
      pickAnOrange?
    else
    puts "There are #{@orangeCount} oranges on the tree"
    pickAnOrange?
    end
  end

  def pickAnOrange?
    puts "Would you like to pick an orange?"
    @wantsApple = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @orangeCount > 0
      if @wantsApple == "yes"
        @orangeCount = @orangeCount - 1
        @tree[""] = "_"
        puts @tree
        puts "That was delicious"
        if @orangeCount < 1
          puts "There are no more oranges left"
        elsif @orangeCount == 1
          puts "There is one more orange left"
          pickAnOrange?
        else
          puts "There are #{@orangeCount} oranges left"
          pickAnOrange?
        end
      elsif @wantsApple == "no"
        puts "Alright, hombre"
      elsif @wantsApple == "exit"
        puts "Goodbye"
        exit
      else
        puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
        pickAnOrange?
      end
    end
    waitOneYear?
  end

  def drawTree
    @tree = <<-'EOF'

                \/ |    |/
              \/ / \||/  /_/___/_
              \/   |/ \/
          _\_\_\    |  /_____/_
                \  | /          /
        __ _-----`  |{,-----------~
                  \ }{
                  }{{
                  }}{
                  {{}
            , -=-~{ .-^- _
        ejm        `}
                    {

      EOF


      @originalTree = <<-'EOF'

                    \/ |    |/
                  \/ / \||/  /_/___/_
                  \/   |/ \/
              _\_\_\    |  /_____/_
                    \  | /          /
            __ _-----`  |{,-----------~
                      \ }{
                      }{{
                      }}{
                      {{}
                , -=-~{ .-^- _
            ejm        `}
                        {

          EOF

  end

end

tree = OrangeTree.new
```

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea.
In case you need to adapt to your code.

```
tree = []

def stats tree
  p fruits_growth = tree.sum{ |t| t[:f] }
  p fruits_eaten = tree.sum{ |t| t[:e] }
  p fruits_on_tree = fruits_growth - fruits_eaten
  p height = tree.sum{ |t| t[:h] }
end

def show_tree tree
  puts
  tree.each { |t| print "" * t[:h]}
  tree.each { |t| print "" * (t[:f] - t[:e]) + "❌" * t[:e] }
  puts
end

def eat_fruits_from tree, n
  eat = n
  tree.each do |t|
    eatable = t[:f] - t[:e]
    next if eatable == 0
    if eat >= eatable
      then
        t[:e] += eatable
        eat -= eatable
      else
        t[:e] += eat
        eat = 0
    end
  end
end

def grow tree, h, f
  tree << {h: h, f: f, e: 0}
end

grow tree, 3, 0
show_tree tree #=> 
grow tree, 4, 2
show_tree tree #=> 
eat_fruits_from tree, 2
show_tree tree #=> ❌❌
grow tree, 4, 4
show_tree tree #=> ❌❌
eat_fruits_from tree, 3
show_tree tree #=> ❌❌❌❌❌
```

The tree array contains a series of hashes like `{:h=>3, :f=>1, :e=>0}`, where `:h` is the delta growth in heigh, `:f` are fruits and `:e` are eaten fruits.
Each time the tree grows a new hash is added to the array. When fruits are eaten, existing hashes are updated.

Comment: This is wonderful. I had no idea this was possible. What are these symbols called?

Comment: Emoji. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626924/how-to-print-unicode-character-u-1f4a9-pile-of-poo-emoji

Comment: My terminal does not show these emojis. Is it only possible to show them via the browser?

Comment: For me it's working on MacOS terminal. I suppose Ubuntu terminal supports it too (https://askubuntu.com/search?q=terminal+emoji). I don't know about Windows.

Comment: check out my/your answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Well, this maybe is a silly Idea but it should work, without modyfing your program so match as you use, text for the visual representation (describing it) of the tree, maybe you can use ASCII diargram of the tree

```
=> :draw_small_tree
[2] pry(main)> draw_small_tree
                                   # #### ####
                                ### /#|### |/####
                               ##/#/ ||/##/_/##/_#
                             ###  /###|/ / # ###
                           ##__#_## | #/###_/_####
                          ## #### #  #| /  #### ##/##
                           __#_--###`  |{,###---###-~
                                      }{
                                      }}{
                                      }}{
                                 ejm  {{}
                                , -=-~{ .-^- _
                                      `}
                                       {
=> nil

def draw_small_tree
  tree = <<-EOF
                                    # #### ####
                                ### \/#|### |/####
                               ##\/#/ \||/##/_/##/_#
                             ###  \/###|/ \/ # ###
                           ##_\_#\_\## | #/###_/_####
                          ## #### # \ #| /  #### ##/##
                           __#_--###`  |{,###---###-~
                                     \ }{
                                      }}{
                                      }}{
                                 ejm  {{}
                                , -=-~{ .-^- _
                                      `}
                                       {
         EOF
puts tree
end
```

You can google for more ASCII tree representations

Comment: That is great and not a silly idea at all. Thank you so much! I wonder how I can best incorporate the oranges though.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Check out my answer I based on yours!